# SVG Scaling Text to fit container

Tags: xml, xhtml, svg, viewbox

This is likely a very simple question, but how do I get text in SVG to stretch to fit its container?

I don't care if it looks ugly from being stretched too long or high, but it needs to fits its container and be as big as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you really don't care that the text gets ugly, here's how to fit unknown length text into a known width.

```
<svg width="436" height="180"
    style="border:solid 6px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <text y="50%" textLength="436" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">UGLY TEXT</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work in IE?  Doesn't seem to work, but I have a lot of other stuff in play.

Comment: You may need to use unbreakable space if your text starts or ends with space.

Comment: It's full horizontally, but is there a way to fill it vertically?

Answer (score 21):

Here is what I have come up with... Its similar to what other people have posted, but I think it resizes and scales nicely.  This code will add spacing to any text roughly between 10-25 characters to make it fill the entire width of its parent.  If you need longer or shorter text, just adjust the viewBox width and textLength attributes.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox='0 0 300 24'>
<text textLength='290' lengthAdjust="spacing" x='5' y="14" >
    Some Unknown Text that is resizing
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This plays with space between letters, does not actually resize the letters, can be useful, but current description is misleading :)

Answer (score 16):

Maybe this could work for you. You'd have to tweak the values, but it does resize when the parent div resizes. [Here's my dabblet example.](http://dabblet.com/gist/5231222) It works similarly to fittext.js

I used the [‘viewBox’](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) & [‘preserveAspectRatio’](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attributes.

```
<svg><text x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em">Look, I’m centered!</text></svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"><text font-size="16" dy=".3em" >I’m also resizeable!</text></svg>
```

other resources I looked at:

- [Making Sense of SVG viewBox's Madness](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox%27s+Madness)
- [How to Style Scalable Vector Graphics Using CSS](http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/)

Comment: you're welcome. it's one of my first contributions to the "internet" so I'm glad to hear I was able to reach somebody. (I'm called Stoikerty now :P)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `textPath` tag in conjunction with the `text` tag. If you then set the `lengthAdjust` attribute of the `textPath` tag to `"spacingAndGlyphs"` (you may additionally use the `method` attribute and set it to `"stretch"` to adjust the rendering method).

Example:

```html
<div style="width: 100%">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 200 100"
      style="border:solid 6px"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g>
      <path id="svg-text" d="M 10 50 H 180" fill="transparent" stroke="lightgray" />

          <text>
          <textPath
                xlink:href="#svg-text"
                method="stretch"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"
              >Beautifully resized!</textPath>
          </text>
      </g>
  </svg>
<div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just bleeds out of the container https://jsbin.com/xecisayuki/1/edit?html,output

Comment: No, that works nice if you add textLength="170" attribute to textPath tag. That value - 170 - is the length of the path defined in its d attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution I came up with:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50">
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="black"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="65%" fill="black">STR</text>
</svg>
```

Here **font-size** helps you to fit the text size within the container.
And to fit the text to the centre of the svg you can use

```
x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, just needed to adjust the font-size attribute to 200% for covering completely the height of container