# How to show SVG with JavaScript in img

Tags: javascript, image, svg

I have a php-file that sends an SVG header and draws itself partly with JavaScript. Everything works fine when I show the SVG directly in the browser. However, when I embed it in an `<img>`, then the JavaScript seems not to be executed. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Here is the php-file (`testsvg.php`):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 version="1.1"
 width="800"
 height="600"
 id="example_text">
    <g id="layer1">
        <text
         x="100"
         y="100"
         id="text_holder">
            <?php echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'text'); ?>
        </text>
    </g>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function create_from_rect (client_rect, offset_px) {
    if (! offset_px) {
        offset_px=0;
    }

    var box = document.createElementNS(
        document.rootElement.namespaceURI,
        'rect'
    );

    if (client_rect) {
        box.setAttribute('x', client_rect.left - offset_px);
        box.setAttribute('y', client_rect.top - offset_px);
        box.setAttribute('width', client_rect.width + offset_px * 2);
        box.setAttribute('height', client_rect.height + offset_px * 2);
    }

    return box;
}

function add_bounding_box (text_id, padding) {
    var text_elem = document.getElementById(text_id);
    if (text_elem) {
        var f = text_elem.getClientRects();
        if (f) {
            var bbox = create_from_rect(f[0], padding);
            bbox.setAttribute(
                'style',
                'fill: none;'+
                'stroke: black;'+
                'stroke-width: 0.5px;'
            );
            text_elem.parentNode.appendChild(bbox);
        }
    }
}

add_bounding_box('text_holder', 10);

</script>
</svg>
```

(The SVG/JavaScript is mostly taken from [How can I draw a box around text with SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001950/how-can-i-draw-a-box-around-text-with-svg/3001968#3001968).)

When I open this file directly in the browser, e.g. with `http://localhost/testsvg.php?text=Test` it draws a proper box around the text `Test`.

However, when I embed it with an `<img>`, e.g. with `<img src="testsvg.php?text=Test" alt="">`, it does not show the box.

Comment: Try to use `<embed>` or `<object>` instead of `<img>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To protect user's privacy, script is not run in images. There are [other restrictions](http://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/).

When thinking of an image it helps to have the mental model "could I do this if I used a raster image"? If you bear that in mind you won't go far wrong as that's basically the model the browsers implement.

Your alternatives are to use `<object>` or `<iframe>` tags instead of `<img>` as they do allow scripting.

Comment: It seems very strange that the `<img>` is not shown properly, but when I click on `View Image` it shows just fine. Well what can you do? That is very unfortunate, since by using `<object>` or `<iframe>` I loose the whole "Save Image As...", "View Image", etc., functionality. Also, is there a way to show the `<object>` by, e.g., half its original size? For the `<img>` I used `onload="this.width*=.5; this.onload=null;"` which seems not to work with `<object>`.

Comment: Best ask a new question for that so you can get proper answers.