# Dynamically create SVG with external .js-file

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to create a SVG (actually created by a `svg.php`-file) with an external .js-file. When putting all the javascript functions directly in the SVG it works properly:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
?>
<svg
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 version="1.1"
 width="800"
 height="600"
 id="example_text">
    <g id="layer1">
        <text
         x="100"
         y="100"
         id="text_holder"
         style="font-size: 12pt;">
            <?php echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'text'); ?>
        </text>
    </g>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function create_from_rect (client_rect, offset_px) {
            if (! offset_px) {
                offset_px=0;
            }

            var box = document.createElementNS(
                document.rootElement.namespaceURI,
                'rect'
            );

            if (client_rect) {
                box.setAttribute('x', client_rect.left - offset_px);
                box.setAttribute('y', client_rect.top - offset_px);
                box.setAttribute('width', client_rect.width + offset_px * 2);
                box.setAttribute('height', client_rect.height + offset_px * 2);
            }

            return box;
        }

        function add_bounding_box (text_id, padding) {
            var text_elem = document.getElementById(text_id);
            if (text_elem) {
                var f = text_elem.getClientRects();
                if (f) {
                    var bbox = create_from_rect(f[0], padding);
                    bbox.setAttribute(
                        'style',
                        'fill: none;'+
                        'stroke: black;'+
                        'stroke-width: 0.5px;'
                    );
                    text_elem.parentNode.appendChild(bbox);
                }
            }
        }

        add_bounding_box('text_holder', 10);
    </script>
</svg>
```

Can be loaded with e.g. `svg.php?text=Test` (Which creates an SVG and draws a box around it. The example is mainly taken from [How can I draw a box around text with SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001950/how-can-i-draw-a-box-around-text-with-svg/3001968#3001968).)

However, I would like to put the javascript functions in an external .js-file. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out where to load it. Putting the functions in `svg.js` and adding a simple `<script src="svg.js"></script>` before the other script in the php-file seems not do to the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG a `<script>` tag uses xlink:href rather than src to point to an external script file so you want

```
<script xlink:href="svg.js"/>
```

If you haven't defined the xlink namespace then you'll need to do so by adding `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` as an attribute of the root `<svg>` element. e.g.

```
<svg
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 version="1.1"
 width="800"
 height="600"
 id="example_text">
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not working, but gives me an "XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace".

Comment: I've expanded my explanation.