# Pure SVG way to fit text to a box

Tags: svg

Box size known. Text string length unknown. Fit text to box without ruining its aspect ratio.

[image]

After an evening of googling and reading the SVG spec, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without JavaScript. The closest I could get was using the `textLength` and `lengthAdjust` text attributes, but that stretches the text along one axis only.

```
<svg width="436" height="180"
    style="border:solid 6px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text y="50%" textLength="436" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">UGLY TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

I am aware of [SVG Scaling Text to fit container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938779/svg-scaling-text-to-fit-container) and [fitting text into the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933857/fitting-text-into-the-box)

Comment: I ended up making a loop in javascript that increases the font size until getBBox shows it would no longer fit. Ugly, so still hoping there would be some other way.

Comment: I have also been trying to get this same functionality to work.  The best method I have found was the same one you did.  Loop through JS and change font until it fits.  But even in fonts there is still some whitespace above and below so you can't seem to get it just right.

Comment: This sucks, it seems like such a basic thing, but the spec is clear that it only stretches it in one direction.  After playing around, I was able to get it close by modifying only the Y scale using transform, aka: `transform="scale(0,5)"` - http://jsfiddle.net/G5L8W/

Comment: I am trying to think if there was a way to calculate the amount of scale being applied to the text on the x axis and apply it to the y axis, but that would then also mean adding in checks to make sure you aren't over scaling the Y, and then you're back at using JS.  I'll bet you could use transform/scale with JS better though.

Comment: built-in support for this in SVG (or any text elements in a webpage) would be fantastic

Comment: http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/TEXT_IN_A_BOX/index.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it directly without Javascript, but I found a JS quite easy solution, without for loops and without modify the font-size and fits well in all dimensions, that is, the text grows until the limit of the shortest side.

Basically, I use the `transform` property, calculating the right proportion between the desired size and the current one.

This is the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
 <text id="t1" y="50" >MY UGLY TEXT</text>
 <script type="application/ecmascript"> 

    var width=500, height=500;

    var textNode = document.getElementById("t1");
    var bb = textNode.getBBox();
    var widthTransform = width / bb.width;
    var heightTransform = height / bb.height;
    var value = widthTransform < heightTransform ? widthTransform : heightTransform;
    textNode.setAttribute("transform", "matrix("+value+", 0, 0, "+value+", 0,0)");

 </script>
</svg>
```

In the previous example the text grows until the `width == 500`, but if I use a box size of `width = 500` and `height = 30`, then the text grows until `height == 30`.

Comment: Or simply...

textNode.setAttribute("transform", "scale("+value+")");

Comment: Quick note- the scale attribute also affects the coordinate system of the current item, so if you want the element to be in the same position, will need to divide both x and y positions by the scalar to get the same relative position

Comment: Or even more simply... set the text `font-size` to 1 (`1em` in our case); then once you have the scale factor (`value` in this answer) just set the `font-size` to it. See example below.

Comment: I also wanted the text to be verticaly-centered, so I changed the end (after `var value = ...`)  to   `textNode.style.transform = "translateY(50%) scale(" + value + ")";
    textNode.style.transformOrigin = '0px 0px';
    textNode.style.dominantBaseline = 'central';`

Comment: I am converting an svg to png using imagemagick and as I thought, this js is not working there. Is there any recommendation to get it work when I am converting SVG to PNG?

Comment: @Krunal, I'd try using Inkscape CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725966/661140

Comment: For vertical and horizontal centering the parameters should be `matrix(value, 0, 0, value, width/2, height/2)` and with `x="0" y="0"`

Comment: when I put this script into my svg Chrome things that less than operator at "widthTransform < heightTransform " is the opening of a new tag and gives "StartTag: invalid element name" error.  Is there a way we should be escaping it or something?

Comment: I figured out my above problem by wrapping the contents of the <script> tag with CDATA:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <script>//<![CDATA[
        …code…
    //]]>
    </script>
</svg>

Answer (score 19):

first of all: just saw that the answer doesn't precisely address your need - it might still be an option, so here we go:

you are rightly observing that svg doesn't support word-wrapping directly. however, you might benefit from `foreignObject` elements serving as a wrapper for xhtml fragments where word-wrapping is available.

have a look at this self-contained demo (<strike>available [online](http://stack.collapsar.bplaced.net/data/so/svg/so.15430189.svg)</strike>):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430189/pure-svg-way-to-fit-text-to-a-box  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="20cm" height="20cm"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
   style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px black;"
>
  <title>simulated wrapping in svg</title>
  <desc>A foreignObject container</desc>

   <!-- Text-Elemente -->
   <foreignObject
      x="100" y="100" width="200" height="150"
      transform="translate(0,0)"
   >
      <xhtml:div style="display: table; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
         <xhtml:div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <xhtml:div style="color:black; text-align:center;">Demo test that is supposed to be word-wrapped somewhere along the line to show that it is indeed possible to simulate ordinary text containers in svg.</xhtml:div>
         </xhtml:div>
      </xhtml:div>
   </foreignObject>

  <rect x="100" y="100" width="200" height="150" fill="transparent" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, but was not interested in word wrapping.

Comment: @collapsar, your demo link is broken

Comment: If I add more text, it will hide, and the font size of the text will not shrink.

Answer (score 6):

I've developed @Roberto answer, but instead of transforming (scaling) the textNode, we simply:

- give it `font-size` of  `1em` to begin with
- calculate the scale based on `getBBox`
- set the `font-size` to that scale

(You can also use `1px` etc.)

Here's the React HOC that does this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextBox from './TextBox';

const AutoFitTextBox = TextBoxComponent =>
  class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.svgTextNode = React.createRef();
      this.state = { scale: 1 };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const { width, height } = this.props;
      const textBBox = this.getTextBBox();
      const widthScale = width / textBBox.width;
      const heightScale = height / textBBox.height;
      const scale = Math.min(widthScale, heightScale);

      this.setState({ scale });
    }

    getTextBBox() {
      const svgTextNode = this.svgTextNode.current;
      return svgTextNode.getBBox();
    }

    render() {
      const { scale } = this.state;
      return (
        <TextBoxComponent
          forwardRef={this.svgTextNode}
          fontSize={`${scale}em`}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  };

export default AutoFitTextBox(TextBox);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its the solution for what you want to do but you can use `textLength`
with percentage `="100%"` for full width.

```
<svg width="436" height="180"
    style="border:solid 6px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="0%" y="50%" textLength="100%">blabla</text>
</svg>
```

you can also add `text-anchor="middle"` and change the `x` position to center perfectly your text

this will not change the fontsize and you will have weird space letterspacing...

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kurokumosan/fz067vac/)

Comment: It yust expands the letter spacing. :(

Comment: Yep, and just to be clear on the text centering - the attribute is "text-anchor" and you would need also x=50% like `<text x="50%" y="50%" textLength="100%" text-anchor="middle">AB</text>`

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue in 2022. There is no way to define bounds and get text to scale in a pure scalable vector graphic. Adjusting the font size manually is still the only solution it seems, and the examples given are quite buggy. Has anybody figured out a clean solution that works? Judging by the svg spec it looks like a pure solution doesn't exist.

And to provide some sort of answer myself, this resource is the best I've found, is hacky, but works much more robustly: [fitrsvgtext - storybook](https://ivnmaksimovic.github.io/fitr-svg-text/?path=/story/fitrsvgtext--limit-width-and-height-no-matter-how-many-characters) | [fitrsvgtext - GitHub](https://github.com/ivnmaksimovic/fitr-svg-text)