# Converting svg to png with inkscape command line failing

Tags: svg, png, inkscape

I feel like I must be doing something silly wrong, but I just can't get this to work. This is the command I am running from cmd:

```
inkscape.com "C:\path\ship.svg" -e --export-png="C:\Path\ship.png" --without-gui
```

In return, I get:

`WARNING: File path "--export-png=C:\path\ship.png" includes directory that doesn't exist.`

It does exist. What am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should have used either `-e` or `--export-png`, not both, since they mean the same thing.

But [According to the docs](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html#SYNOPSIS), `-e` and `--export-png` are no longer available. You should use `-o` or `--export-filename=FILENAME` instead. And still, you can use only one of them since `-o` is just the shortcut for `--export-filename`.

```
inkscape "C:\path\ship.svg" -o "C:\path\ship.png"
```

or

```
inkscape "C:\path\ship.svg" --export-filename="C:\path\ship.png"
```

Comment: not sure why not work for me. though I am on mac os.

Comment: Hi @GeneCode I never worked on a mac, so I don't know, but there is this page on the InkScape wiki describes some issues and solutions regarding file paths. Maybe that helps?
https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Mac_OS_X

Comment: *just* managed to make it work on my Mac. Using latest Inkscape V1.0. I wrote a blog on  it too if anybody is interested. https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2020/08/how-to-automation-export-png-in.html

Comment: On my Mac, it's workd.
Maybe you need to specify full path, in my case `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape`
You can also add it to the the path, or create a symbolic link to the app `ln -s /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape /usr/local/bin/inkscape`

Answer (score 14):

Just an update for 2021:

```bash
inkscape \
    --export-width=128 \
    --export-type=png \
    --export-filename="C:\path\ship.png" \
    "C:\path\build.svg"
```

or if you want transparent PNGs, add `--export-background-opacity=0`:

```bash
inkscape \
    --export-background-opacity=0 \
    --export-width=128 \
    --export-type=png \
    --export-filename="C:\path\ship.png" \
    "C:\path\build.svg"
```

Answer (score 1):

In inkscape version 1.0.2 following command will work:

```
inkscape --export-type="png" myfile.svg --export-filename=myfile.png
```