# Why is text not showing along this svg textPath?

Tags: svg

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938779/svg-scaling-text-to-fit-container) I am trying to render svg text such that it fits into a given space (auto sized, I do not give font size explicitly).

Here is my test image

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="200" height="200"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <g fill="black">
            <polygon points="1.0,0.0 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384"></polygon>
        </g>
        <g fill="red">
            <polygon points="0.94,0.0 -0.46999999999999975,0.8140638795573724 -0.4700000000000004,-0.814063879557372"></polygon>
        </g>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="0.94,0.0 0.614374448177051,0.18800000000000003 0.6143744481770509,-0.18799999999999994"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="-0.46999999999999975,0.8140638795573724 -0.4699999999999999,0.43806387955737236 -0.14437444817705086,0.6260638795573723"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="-0.4700000000000004,-0.814063879557372 -0.14437444817705136,-0.6260638795573721 -0.47000000000000025,-0.438063879557372"></polygon>
        <circle fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.47"></circle>
        <circle fill="blue" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.37"></circle>
        <path id="text_path_XQjkCgSWaBUILYrAVcMt" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.01" d="M0,0 L0.5,0.5"></path>
        <text><textPath xlink:href="#text_path_XQjkCgSWaBUILYrAVcMt" method="stretch" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">look at me</textPath></text>
    </svg>
```

The `<path>` renders in the expected position, but I don't see `look at me` rendered along that line or anywhere else.

What is wrong with my `<textPath>`?

Comment: Just quick fiddling around: If you add `textLength="0.7"` to your `textPath` the text is at least some kind of "visible". And adding `font-size="0.2"` makes it very readable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: In order to see the text please add `svg{font-size:.16px}` in the css. In this moment the font size is 16 and your viewBox is very small: 'viewBox="-1 -1 2 2"'

Answer (score 1):

Because it's way too big and falls off the end of the path.

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="200" height="200"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <g fill="black">
            <polygon points="1.0,0.0 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384"></polygon>
        </g>
        <g fill="red">
            <polygon points="0.94,0.0 -0.46999999999999975,0.8140638795573724 -0.4700000000000004,-0.814063879557372"></polygon>
        </g>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="0.94,0.0 0.614374448177051,0.18800000000000003 0.6143744481770509,-0.18799999999999994"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="-0.46999999999999975,0.8140638795573724 -0.4699999999999999,0.43806387955737236 -0.14437444817705086,0.6260638795573723"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="orange" points="-0.4700000000000004,-0.814063879557372 -0.14437444817705136,-0.6260638795573721 -0.47000000000000025,-0.438063879557372"></polygon>
        <circle fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.47"></circle>
        <circle fill="blue" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.37"></circle>
        <path id="text_path_XQjkCgSWaBUILYrAVcMt" fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.01" d="M0,0 L0.5,0.5"></path>
        <text><textPath font-size="0.15px" xlink:href="#text_path_XQjkCgSWaBUILYrAVcMt" method="stretch" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">look at me</textPath></text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: The intent is for the renderer to select a size suitable for making the text fit into whatever path I give it without me giving the font size explicitly. Is this possible?

Comment: Write some javascript to scale the text to fit.

Comment: This is not being rendered in a browser, it's for a static asset to be imported into documents.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for you then. Parse the font file, figure out how big the glyphs are, measure the path somehow and scale the font to fit.